# Laravel 7 multi auth with 3 different tables

Tags: database-design, laravel-7, laravel-authentication

I'm new to Laravel 7 and i'm creating an application that requires 3 different user tables ( Admin , salesperson, warehouse manager )
Each user can login from a separate login form and has a different dashboard.
I want to implement authentication for each user , to login to their specified dashboard , the users have different columns , which is why I wish to keep them in separate tables instead of one table with a role column.

Answer (score 2):

you should add the three tables in the **config/auth.php** in the guards and providers to make the auth() function recognize each table: *note to replace it with your models name*

```
    'guards' => [
       'admin' => [
          'driver'     => 'session',
          'provider'   => 'admin',
        ],
   'salesperson' => [
          'driver'     => 'session',
          'provider'   => 'salesperson',
        ],
   'manager' => [
          'driver'     => 'session',
          'provider'   => 'manager',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
        'salesperson' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Salesperson::class,
        ],

        'manager' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Manager::class,
        ],
    ],
```

After that you should create a middleware for each one to control the login, so you should add it in the middleware **$routemiddleware** function, In the **kernel.php**:

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateAdmin::class,
'salesperson' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSalesperson::class,
'manager' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateManager::class,
```

create a controller for each one:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Admin;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
      use AuthenticatesUsers;

      public function __construct()
      {
          $this->middleware('guest');
      }

      public function login(Request $request)
    {
              $this->validate($request, [
                  'email' => 'required|email',
                  'password' => 'required',
              ]);
              if (auth()->guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {
                  return redirect('*your route*');
              } else {
                  dd('your username and password are wrong.');
              }
    }

      public function getLogin()
      {
          return view('*the login form*');
      }
}
```

and in your **Admin.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Relative extends Authenticatable
{
  use Notifiable;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $hidden = [
      'password'
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
      return $this->password;
    }

}
```

repeate the last two steps in for each one. If ypu need more information: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/multi-auth-login-with-single-table-user-using-middleware-in-laravel